# Excel 2013 VBA ListObject Table Resize won't work

Tags: vba, excel, listobject

I'm trying to dynamically resize a ListObject table after pasting data in the rows below with VBA. Resizing works fine as long as Sheet02, where it happens, is the active sheet - but throws an error when Sheet02 is not the active sheet. What am I missing?

**Code snippet:**

```
Function Resize()
  lastRow = Sheet02.Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
  newRange = "$A1:$G$" & lastRow
  Sheet02.ListObjects("tblDb").Resize Range(newRange)
End Function
```

**The Error:** *Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error*

Comment: What's `Sheet02`?  Where do you declare that?  You need something like `Worksheets("Sheet02").Cells(...)` or `Dim Sheet02 as Worksheet // Set Sheet02 = Worksheets("Sheet2")`, no?

Comment: As explained below, you can refer to Sheet codenames directly. Renamed in this way, because reasons - including but not limited to changing display names of sheets and (kinda OCD) ordering of the important ones in VBA editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running some more tests with data below the table *put there by hand* revealed no issues with any errors whatsoever - not within the sheet, nor from outside of it.

The problem in my case was as follows:

I was **importing data from a .CSV file by using QueryTables.Add**, utilizing the import utility Excel comes with. Turns out in doing so, it **creates a Query Connection**, a live "Link" to the file you imported, so it can automatically update itself with new data from that file should it change.

Using the import within the existing Table object in Excel didn't work, because **Table objects and Query Connection content don't get along** particularly well, as it turns out. At this point you might realize where this is going.

So I expanded the code to import from the .CSV just below the table, then proceeded to remove the Query Connection from the sheet, and resize the table over the now disconnected, plain text contents of the imported .CSV file.

The ImportCSV function just so happened to include this particular snippet of code:

```
For Each queryConnec In ActiveSheet.QueryTables
  queryConnec.Delete
Next queryConnec
```

And that's the reason why it worked within the Sheet - because I **imported** from within the sheet and the **Query Connections have been removed** in doing so. When **importing from outside** the sheet, the Query Connections were of course **not removed**, which is why resizing the Table over the live Query Connection content threw an error...

Fixed easily by:

```
For Each queryConnec In Sheet02.QueryTables
  queryConnec.Delete
Next queryConnec
```

**tl;dr: A tiny oversight for a programmer, turned into a huge issue for Excel.**

Answer (score 0):

Try not updating the screen and changing the focus to sheet02. Next, make your change to sheet02. Finally, return the focus to whatever sheet you were on.

```
Function Resize()
Let Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim Current_Worksheet As Worksheet
Dim Sheet_02 As Worksheet

Set Current_Worksheet = ActiveSheet

Set Sheet_02 = Sheet02

Let lastRow = Sheet_02.Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
Let newRange = "$A1:$G$" & lastRow

Call Sheet_02.Activate
DoEvents
Sheet_02.ListObjects("tblDb").Resize Range(newRange)
DoEvents
Call Current_Worksheet.Activate

Let Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Function
```

Comment: I don't believe `Sheet02` is a valid VBA reference.

Comment: You are allowed to modify that in the sheet's properties to any name you would like. Much like naming a range to something other than "A1".  I have to assume that is what he did. Or you would be correct that Sheet02 should be something like Sheets(2).

Comment: Oh I never knew that you could rename the sheet in the Properties.  I wonder why one would do that, instead of renaming the sheet altogether. ...but that's a different question entirely.  Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Referring to the sheet codename property https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-codename-property-excel

Comment: Oooh my god. I found my problem. I removed my older comments as to not waste anyones time more than needed, here's what happened: I used **QueryTables.Add** to import data from a **.CSV file** before resizing, and had to add code to **remove the links it automatically creates** in excel (to refresh the data on its own) when doing so. I did, and it worked fine, I just forgot I used *For Each queryConnec In **ActiveSheet**.QueryTables, queryConnec.Delete* ... and ActiveSheet was **not** Sheet02 anymore, of course... so, the table clashed with the existing query connection within those cells...!

Comment: But that's some nice, outside-the-box thinking either way, so here, have a point!